# Word for presenting love

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, meaning-in-context

Looking for a word/phrase to state a situation between like and love. In fact, this is aimed to present a likeliness that is growing to be love.

Basically, how to define a spectrum for the love from the first sight to final stage, e.g. marriage.

Comment: What makes you think marriage is the "final" stage of love?

Comment: @Robusto The OP said ‘eg’ not ‘ie’, you are extrapolating your way to an unsupported conclusion.

Comment: @Spagirl: I'm extrapolating nothing. The words are OP's, not mine.

Comment: You asked why the OP thought marriage ‘**the** final stage’, which admits no other final stage. The OP said ‘final stage, eg marriage’... eg-*for example*, allows other final stages.

Answer (score 2):

This: Like ... add fire ... LOVE!

[image: love.jpg]

Comment: Interesting!! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions: "Likeliness" is similar to the word "likelihood." It does not have anything to do with "liking" or more liking towards loving. Likeliness means the increasing or relative probability something will happen. "Likely" means "probably so" or a probable outcome. "Likeness" also has nothing to do with liking, or like, it refers to to an image or similarity in appearance. So, back to your question. We assume this is the scale of friendship. At bottom that is what liking and loving people is presumed to be about. In English there are many ways to express the relative affection you feel toward another person, once you know them more than as an acquaintance. You like each other. Then you increase your liking to say fondness, then very fond, as you begin to fall in love, which (hopefully) will deepen over time. If you look up synonyms for fond, cherish, regard, feel amorous about, love, madly in love with, you will find a whole range of ways of expressing this.

Answer (score 0):

I should think probably [commitment](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/commitment), in practically every sense of the word.

Source: Vocabulary.com/dictionary/commitment